# Using Linq to XML using C#, how do I find attribute values?

Tags: linq

I need to get all activities for specific claim ID =  13 using linq C#, I am trying the below code, but it's not working.

```
 XDocument Doc = XDocument.Load(DownloadedPath);
    var Activites = (from e in Doc.Descendants("Activity")
                  where (string)Doc.Element("Claim").Element("ID") == 13
```

below is the Xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Advice>
  <Claim>
    <ID>12</ID>
    <ProviderID>CL-MC-0012-07</ProviderID>
    <Activity>
      <ID>20131520320</ID>
      <Start>24/07/2013 13:00</Start>
      <Type>3</Type>
    </Activity>
    <Activity>
      <ID>20131520321</ID>
      <Start>24/07/2013 13:00</Start>
      <Type>3</Type>
    </Activity>
  </Claim>
  <Claim>
    <ID>13</ID>
    <ProviderID>CL-MC-0012-07</ProviderID>
    <Activity>
      <ID>20132058590</ID>
      <Start>20/10/2013 09:00</Start>
      <Type>3</Type>
    </Activity>
    <Activity>
      <ID>20132058591</ID>
      <Start>20/10/2013 09:00</Start>
      <Type>3</Type>
    </Activity>
  </Claim>
```

Comment: Your title talks about attributes... but there are no attributes in this document. If you mean "element values" (which I suspect) you should edit your post. Additionally, "its not working" is never a good description of what happens. Are you getting a compile-time error? An exception? Just no results?

Answer (score 2):

You're currently converting the value to a `string` but then comparing it with an `int`. Don't do that - it's not going to work :)

It's probably simplest to convert it to an `int` instead:

```
var Activites = (from e in Doc.Descendants("Activity")
                 where (int)Doc.Element("Claim").Element("ID") == 13   
                 ...)
```

Next, look at your XML - the `Claim` element isn't inside an `Activity` element... you probably just want:

```
var activities = doc.Descendants("Claim")
                    .Where(claim => (int) claim.Element("ID") == 13)
                    .SelectMany(claim => claim.Elements("Activity"));
```

This finds all `Claim` elements with an ID of 13 (of which there will probably only be one) and then selects its activities, using `SelectMany` so that the result will be a sequence of activity elements, rather than a sequence of sequences...

Comment: @AymanJbr: Yes - it's important to become familiar with LINQ using both query expressions and "dot notation". Query expressions are just converted into "dot notation" by the compiler. See http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2011/01/28/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-41-how-query-expressions-work/